# How to get multiple entries on one variable in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this:

```
var weekend weekstart
x   50_13   43_13
```

I need this:

```
 var week
   x  43
   x  44
   x  45
   x  46
   x  47
   x  48
   x  49
   x  50
```

What is the way out?

Comment: Be more specific. What is the first thing? Is it query result, or table, or object variable in PL/SQL. How many rows are there? Do you need SQL or procedural code? What have you already tried?

Comment: I have only three columns. var, weekstart and weekend. but i have multiple rows. I need to generate a record for every week for every variable.

Comment: You can see it as ungrouping, but the problem is I don't have a list of values to ungroup by. I have to generate all the numbers falling between weekstart and weekend.

Comment: You will have to use pl/sql.  A priori, doing that with straight SQL is not straightforward at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```
CREATE TABLE weeks ( var VARCHAR2(10), weekend VARCHAR2(5), weekstart VARCHAR2(5));
INSERT INTO weeks VALUES ('x', '50_13','43_13');

WITH 
startDay AS
    (SELECT var, MIN(TO_DATE('01-01-2000','dd-mm-yyyy') + LEVEL) AS start_date
    FROM weeks
    WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-01-2000','dd-mm-yyyy') + LEVEL, 'IW_RR') = weekstart
    CONNECT BY TO_DATE('01-01-2000','dd-mm-yyyy') + LEVEL < TO_DATE('01-01-2100','dd-mm-yyyy')
    GROUP BY var),
endDay AS
    (SELECT var, MIN(TO_DATE('01-01-2000','dd-mm-yyyy') + LEVEL) AS end_date
    FROM weeks
    WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-01-2000','dd-mm-yyyy') + LEVEL, 'IW_RR') = weekend
    CONNECT BY TO_DATE('01-01-2000','dd-mm-yyyy') + LEVEL < TO_DATE('01-01-2100','dd-mm-yyyy')
    GROUP BY var)
SELECT var, TO_CHAR(start_date + 7*(LEVEL-1), 'IW') AS week
FROM startDay
    JOIN endDay USING (var)
CONNECT BY start_date + 7*(LEVEL-1) <= end_date;

VAR WEEK
x   43
x   44
x   45
x   46
x   47
x   48
x   49
x   50
```

Precondition is, inital date (01-01-2000) must be smaller than the least number which may appear in your table and max date (01-01-2100) is bigger than greatest number which may appear.

Comment: btw, it works also if your range passes any new year.

Answer (score 0):

This somewhat solves my problem:

```
select x, weekstart + level - 1
from 
myTable
connect by level <= weekend - weekstart + 1
```

Comment: This look different, I doubt that you can add anyting to **string** "43_13"

Comment: @Wernfried - This will only work when we only have week numbers in one single year. My bad. Your method is correct :)